# Too many errors

Tags: heroku, discord, discord.js

This is the error I start with:

```
npm ERR! missing script: start 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: 
npm ERR! /app/.npm/_logs/2020-08-10T10_15_35_198-debug.log
```

then continues from this

```
State changed from crashing to starting
Starting process with command `node idex.js`
State changed from starting to up
Process exited with status 1
State changed from up to crashed
```

still...

```
ReferenceError: client is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/music.js:10:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:20)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:100
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:9:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. "Too many errors" is a _terrible_ question title. Titles should concisely summarize the problem, and this one tells us absolutely nothing about the content of your question.

Answer (score 0):

**missing script: start**

You're probably using `npm start [script]`.
You need to configure your package.json "scripts" object.
It requires a `"start": "your/file"` in the "scripts" object, to start with.
Here's an example.

```
    "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
      "start": "nodemon src/server.js",
      "dev": "src/server.js"
    }
```

**client is not defined**

In `music.js`, line 10, you have a variable `client` that hasn't seemed to be defined, thus it is unable to access it.

All this leads to your file being unable to start and crashing constantly, which is shown in your second image.